# Value of cookies variable is not passing in another controller when using Mozilla Firefox in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mozilla

I am trying to set a cookies variable in users controller like
*cookies[:uuid] = user.uuid*
and then passing this to home controller like
*@a = cookies[:uuid]*
The value of cookies[:uuid] is getting passed in chrome but not in firefox. I checked in logs when using firefox value of cookies:[uuid] is nil. Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: In you're code you're always using `cookies[:uuid]`, right? Your question has it spelled three different ways (`cookies[::uuid]`, `cookies[:uuid]`, and `cookie:[uuid]`)

Comment: If you open the developer tools in Chrome and Firefox, and look at the Network tab, you should be able to see the request (including the 'Cookies' header).  Can you verify that you see the cookie in the chrome network tab, but not in the firefox network tab?

Comment: Any change cookies are disabled in Firefox?

Comment: sorry...my fault everywhere it is cookies[:uuid] so corrected that.                    Also I am not very sure about Network tab but under Application tab(Storage tab in firefox) in cookies section I can see my cookies variables and their values as well in chrome but not in firefox.

Comment: @Rogier I don't think that cookies are disabled in firefox.